# Android GooglePlay LocationClient is null, although initialized in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-play-services, android-location

I am working with the Google Play LocationClient. I have initialized it in onCreate() as stated in the docs:

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

and I am doing a connect in onStart()

```
mLocationClient.connect();
```

It works fine in my Android phone, but in the Developers Console I see that a NullPointerException is happening in the `connect()`line. 
How can this happen?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: There is a lot of stuff happening in onCreate(). Initialzing TextViews, Variables, ActionBar, Fragments,... Don't know how this would help. It works on my device and another one

Comment: Post the LogCat output for the exception that you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because the device that cause the NPE does not have Google Play Service or is not up to dated. In onCreate you can check

```
int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
{
        if (DEBUG) {Log.d(TAG, "errorCode = " + errorCode);}
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 
                                1, new DialogCancelListener());
        errorDialog.show();
}
```

Which will show a dialog to ask the user to go to Google Store to update or install.
In onStart you need to check for null

```
if (mLocationClient != null)
{
    mLocationClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was true. onStart() is called when GooglePlayServices are not available and so the NullPointer happened