# Service onStartCommand throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-service

I have an app that runs two separate services. One of them runs smoothly, and the other works without issue a majority of the time, but is throwing a `NullPointerException` within `onStartCommand()` intermittently on a significant number of newer devices (Samsung, HTC, LG) on varying Android versions between 4.1 and 4.4.2. I am unable to reproduce the error on any of my own devices, including two of the exact models which have experienced this issue. The stacktrace is as follows, indicating the problem is on line 145:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.mycom.myapp.MyLocService@425ab718
with Intent { cmp=com.mycom.myapp/.MyLocService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2695)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5168)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycom.myapp.MyLocService.onStartCommand(MyLocService.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2678)
... 10 more
```

I am using a portion of the code linked within the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111355/1992342) by [blackcj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2620320/blackcj) to run a location service in the background of my app; here is the relevant snippet from MyLocService.java, with the offending line marked:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInProgress = false;
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    locIntent = new Intent(MY_LOCATION);
}

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);      // <----- NPE AT LINE 145

    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();

    if(!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting()) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
    if(mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }
}
```

The service is started by the following code within `onCreate()` in MyActivity.java:

```
Intent MyLocService = new Intent(this, MyLocService.class);     
startService(MyLocService);
```

The service is declared within the `<application>` element in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
    <service
         android:name=".MyLocService"
         android:singleUser="true"
         android:stopWithTask="false" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.mycom.myapp.MyLocService" />
         </intent-filter>
     </service>
```

I have been unable to determine what is causing this exception, as it does not happen consistently and I cannot reproduce it myself. What could be causing this intermittent problem?

Comment: sure that is the line that causes NPE. Make you clean and build and post the updated stacktrace. I doubt that line does not cause NPE

Comment: How do you initialise `mLocationClient`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280205/833647

Comment: @Raghunandan I have indicated what is line 145 in the code, which is the only clue the stacktrace is providing me. I am unable to reproduce the issue myself; these are reports I am receiving from users running the production version of the app.

Comment: You should do a null check before you call any methods (`isConnected()`, `isConnecting()`) on location client. See the link I posted above.

Comment: @KenWolf I added additional code that should clarify.

Comment: You should still do a null check before calling `isConnected()` and `isConnecting()` (even after you have called the constructor and think it cannot be null at this point) - it is null at this point and that is causing the NPE

Comment: @KenWolf Ok, I didn't realize that was a possibility -- the NPE indicating line 145 didn't have me focusing on that. I will add some checks and see how it goes, thx.

Comment: @KenWolf Despite adding null checks there, the same error seems to persist.

Comment: I think I was wrong about this and this is your problem. Have a look at some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5856955/833647. Also, you can try simply not calling the `super` method of `onStartCommand`, it does not seem to be required: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that returning `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` instead of `START_STICKY` has resolved this problem. Instead of continuing to figure out how to check for a null intent, I found a method that supposedly will not cause it in the first place.

I will update with any further conclusions I discover regarding this method as it becomes more widely implemented by my users.